# Deriving the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality

Tags: real-analysis

This question comes from *Real Analysis* by H.L. Royden.

> Let $f$ and $g$ belong to $L^2(E)$. From the linearity of integration show that for any number $A$,
>   $$A^2 \int_E f^2 + 2A \int_E fg + \int_E g^2= \int_E(Af+g)^2 > 0.$$
>   From this and the quadratic formula directly derive the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality.

Comment: What are "E" and "J"  here?

Comment: I've added typesetting to hopefully make the question legible without changing what you intended. Please edit if that is not the case. For starters, I would suggest explaining why $\int_E fg$ and $\int_E(Af + g)^2$ exist and are finite.

Comment: Also clearly the inequality should be $\geq$, not $>$. Consider $f = g = 0$. Presumably also $A$ should be a real number.

Answer (score 1):

The choice $A:=-\frac{\int_E fg}{\int_E f^2}$ gives $$-\frac{(\int_E fg)^2}{\int_E f^2}+\int_E g^2\ge0,$$which rearranges to the desired $\int_E f^2\int_E g^2\ge(\int_E fg)^2$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: The expression is a quadratic in terms of $A$. As it is always $\geq 0$, what does this say about its discriminant?